# Question about proof of Heine-Cantor (i.e. compact and continuous implies uniform continuous)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If anyone has seen the wikipedia page for the Heine-Cantor theorem, I find something off about the proof it presents. It would be incredibly tedious to write it all out here because it's pretty involved, but you can find it at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem).

At a certain point in the proof, after $\delta$ has been defined, the author goes on to say that for all $x,y$ in the domain $M$, $d(x,y)<\delta$. Can anyone corroborate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what it says: suppose that $d_X(x,y) < \delta$ for two arbitrary points of $X$. It might have been less confusing for you if the proof had said: "let $x,y$ be two arbitrary points of $X$ such that $d_X(x,y) < \delta$" instead:

Reason: we want to show

$$\forall x,y \in X: d_X(x,y) < \delta \implies d_Y(f(x),f(y)) < \varepsilon$$

so we start by assuming we have two points in $X$ that are distance $< \delta$ apart, and these must be *arbitrary points* with that property, it doesn't mean that all points of $X$ are $< \delta$ apart, but if we happen to have any two that are, we must show that the distance of their images is $< \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much.